# StringType for Nhibernate Mapping By Code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hey guys I'm trying to map my property name whose type in my code is String. When I crete the mapping class and try to assign a type to it I use this syntax:

Property(x => x.Name, m => 
      {
         ...
         m.Type(new StringType());
         ...
      });

And it's giving me an error, saying that the constructor call isn't valid. But this syntax is valid for all the other types I used (Int32, Boolean and DateTime).

I also tried typing m.Type<string>(); but that ended with an error in the tests I ran.

Comment: String is the default for String properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
using NHibernate;

Property(x => x.Name, map =>
{
    map.Column("SomeColumnName");
    map.Access(Accessor.Property);
    map.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
    });
```